# MCP23S17 not outputing the desired output

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi

I have a MCP23S17 GPIO expansion connected to my raspberry pi. I am using it to switch mosfets that controls multiple LEDs

I am using this [RPIMCP23S17](https://pypi.org/project/RPiMCP23S17/) python library upon trying its example code that supposedly toggles ON and OFF all the channels of the MCP, I am not getting anything from the LEDs,

So i began looking for the cause problem, I tried replacing the chip thinking it may be a bad one but still the same result. My circuit is below BCM 6 and BCM 8 (CE0) share the same connection because of the board i have,

[image]

I tried tinkering with the code a little bit and use some third party software that looks at the state of the GPIO pins.

```
from RPiMCP23S17.MCP23S17 import MCP23S17
import time

import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 100000   #have to slow down the SPI bus so that i can look at the states in piscope

mcp1 = MCP23S17(bus=0x00, pin_cs=0x00, device_id=0x00)
mcp1.open()

for x in range(0, 16):
    mcp1.setDirection(x, mcp1.DIR_OUTPUT)


while(True):
    print ("Toggling all Pins ON")
    for x in range(0, 16):
        mcp1.digitalWrite(x, MCP23S17.LEVEL_HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code do yeild some results but definitely not the desired one it turns on 4 out of 14 leds but for a very very short amount of time, it does not stay. Atleast this somewhat confirms that the chip is recieving the signal

but when i look into piscope it would seem that MISO pin is not recieving(or output??) anything

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why are there no power pins on U4 in your schematic? Assuming you did not forget to connect them, still, did you check the power supply to U4?

Comment: Proteus hides power and ground pins by default, its there do not worry. Just double checked it now, there is 3v3 on the power pin

Comment: You're missing a digitalRead after the ```mcp1.digitalWrite(x, MCP23S17.LEVEL_HIGH)``` (Do also add the delay after the write, as shown in http://wiringpi.com/extensions/spi-mcp23s08-mcp23s17/)

Comment: I have tried using the code for wiringPi, i am getting the same results. no response from the miso, and this time 1 LED stay dimmly on ( it should be blinking really fast basing on the code) out of 11 basing on the code. It makes me think now that there is something wrong with the hardware since 2 libraries are failing